# Should I use "multiple" and "at once" in one sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

I need to describe an app that lets users post to many social services at once.
Is it correct to say "update multiple services at once"?

I'm open to alternative suggestions.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, but I'd be more comfortable with *several services at once* or *multiple services simultaneously*, depending on how technical you are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that there's nothing wrong in this phrase, as long as "multiple" refers to the noun "services".

Answer (score 1):

**At once** has at least two different, but related [meanings](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at+once)

> 1 at the same time : simultaneously
>
> 2 immediately

While your usage may be comfortable with both, there could be circumstances where the *immediately* may be understood, but where you wanted to focus on *at the same time*.